# Regex to match only words without _ or -

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to extract word out of a text file which contains exactly one word per each line. But I only want to match  the word if there are no "_"(underscore) or "-" (dash) in the word:
File might look like :

1. < someword
2. < SomeOtherword
3. < wordwith-dash-anotherd
4. < wordwith_under_anotheru

I only want to extract line 1 & 2 and ignore line 3 & 4
(i.e. result when regex match each line should be:
 someword
  SomeOtherword
 without "<" and space for each line) 
I have been trying with "[\w-]+" which matches words with both _ & -
I am using PowerShell regex engine.

I am processing a file with close to 100000 lines. I don't want to loop through each line as need the processing time to be very quick. code I am using:

> $rx = '[\w-]+' 
>   Get-Content $filename | Select-String -Pattern $rx -AllMatches | select -ExpandProperty Matches | select -ExpandProperty Value | out-file $outputfile

Comment: I need this done via regex as I cannot loop through the content of the file I am processing close to 100000 lines and need to process quickly. $rx = "^[a-zA-Z]+$" Get-Content $ofile | Select-String -Pattern $rx -AllMatches | select -ExpandProperty Matches | select -ExpandProperty Value <br/> "^[a-zA-Z]+$" is not matching ..

Comment: What do you mean by "I don't want to loop through each line"? How else are you going to check if each line has a dash or underscore? I processed a 100k line (~6MB) file in 4 seconds using my answer. Is that not fast enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are performance sensitive, this approach is measurably faster (2.6 secs vs. 80 millisecs):

```
(Select-String '^[a-zA-Z]+$' file.txt -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

This does require a feature that is new to PowerShell v3. You don't say which version you are using.

Comment: You sure about those timings? I tried this with writing the results out to a file (just took my answer and stuck a `add-content` on the end of pipeline) and got more like 11s vs 7s. Measurable, but not a factor of 30 difference.

Comment: Yup. `(measure-command {(Select-String '^[a-zA-Z]+$' file.txt -AllMatches).Matches.Value}).TotalSeconds` spits out 0.0857457 and `(measure-command {gc 'file.txt' | where { $_ -notmatch '-|_' } | foreach { $_.Trim('<', ' ') }}).TotalSeconds` spits out 2.8649068 on my HP Z420 running Windows 8.1 on an SSD.

Comment: Yea I've got a similar setup (Windows 8.1 on an SSD). I ran a few different regexes on my file and I think where this one really shines is when you want just a few lines out of the file. That is the performance gain is mostly due to keeping strings out of the pipeline. My first test matched most of the lines in the file thus a smaller difference. Using a more restrictive filter that only pulls a few dozen lines out of 100k showed a difference of 3.7s vs 200ms.

Comment: Thanks. This resolved my problem. Sorry about being so pedantic about processing. My script does lot of other processor intensive stuff which altogether adds up to total time it take to run the script. So I am trying to keep each sub process to minimum delay.

Answer (score 1):

To do a regex match in powershell you can use either `-match` operator or `select-string`. There is also a `-notmatch` operator and a `-NotMatch` flag for `select-string`. Both filter for the absence of a match.

So one option is

```
gc 'file.txt' | where { $_ -notmatch '-|_' } | foreach { $_.Trim('<', ' ') }
```

and another is

```
gc 'file.txt' | select-string -NotMatch '-|_' | foreach { $_.Line.Trim('<', ' ') }
```